# Symlink support in IIS Express (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: iis, windows-7, symlink, ntfs, iis-express

Can I use symbolic links to files created by `mklink <link> <target>` in IIS7 and/or IIS Express?

I have created a simple HTML (it's MVC3 Razor but it's not the problem) project with line:

`<link href="foo.js">`

Then I moved `foo.js` file to another directory and created a link to this file using:

`mklink foo.js bar\foo.js`

HTML remains the same.

FireBug shows (on network tab) file size 0B (for discussion), because such a file in the system actually is 0B. The problem is that FireBug does not read the contents of a file or file is not served by IIS Express properly.

IE behaves similarly.

I'm using IIS Express with VS2010 for development, not tested yet on IIS7, the operating system is Windows 7 x64.

Hard links created by command:

`mklink / h <link> <target>`

works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing for an image but using a symbolic link - so without the "/H" - and got the same result when I tried to use Visual Studio 2010's internal web server (Cassini).

Perhaps IIS Express does have the same the limitation, because when I retried using IIS on my Win 7 (64bit) laptop the image was server correctly.

Cheers